# Find contents of parentheses that start with UPPERCASE letter?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I want to grab the contents of parentheses, excluding the parentheses.
Then add a colon to the end plus font items shown below.

Before: `(Woman 1), (Ki-Woo), (Drunk)`

After: `<font color="#FF4500"><b>Woman 1:</b></font>`

Here's what I have so far:

Find: `(\([A-Z]*(?:(\h*|-)[A-Z0-9][a-z]*)*\))`

Replace: `\<font color\=\"\#FFA500\"\>\<b\>($1)\:\<\/b\>\<\/font\>`

Currently mine still includes the brackets in the Find.

Comment: @ Hank,  in my editor your code and Kugelman's code, both gives the same result..(Woman 1), <font color="#FF4500"><b>Woman 1:</b></font>, <font color="#FF4500"><b>Woman 1:</b></font>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the pattern that you tried, you can switch the capture group to the inner part of the parenthesis, and make the second capture group a non capturing one.

Then use group 1 in the replacement.

```
\(([A-Z]*(?:(?:\h*|-)[A-Z0-9][a-z]*)*)\)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0th0c1/1)

To not match empty parenthesis, you might write the pattern as:

```
\(([A-Z][a-z]*(?:(?:\h*|-)[A-Z0-9][a-z]*)*)\)
```

- `\(` Match `(`
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[A-Z][a-z]*` Match a single char A-Z and optional chars a-z
  - `(?:` Non capture group to repeat as a whole part

    - `(?:\h*|-)` Match either 0+ horizontal whitspace chars or a single `-`
    - `[A-Z0-9][a-z]*` Match a single char A-Z and optional chars a-z
  - `)*` Close and repeat the non capture group 0+ times
- `)` Close group 1
- `\)` Match `)`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EuPgpf/1)

Note that this part of the pattern `(?:\h*|-)` can match either optional horizontal whitespace chars, or a single hyphen, and matches `Ki Woo` but could also match `KiWoo`

In the replacement use group 1 using `$1`

```
<font color="#FF4500"><b>$1</b></font>
```

[image]

Comment: Thank You ... much appreciate the very clear explanation, absolutely wonderful   ... just what this noob needed ... TY again

Answer (score 0):

Short code as always is below, just checked by me,  Working perfect...

Find: `\(([\w \d-]*)\)`
Replace All: `\<font color\=\"\#FFA500\"\>\<b\>$1\:\<\/b\>\<\/font\>`